# A problem with short i

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels

I can't repeat short i when I'm hearing it (I currently use long e instead of short i). How do I learn that or may that be impossible for me?

Comment: Hi Razip, welcome to ELL! Are you talking about the 'i' in sit, or the 'i' at ends of words like "happy"?

Comment: Like "will", "sit", "with".

Comment: Exercise with someone or something that would tell you what it hears you say.  I recall using a shrink-wrap software package to try to improve my English in 1990s. It came with a microphone and allowed to record the phrase and would gauge how close you were to what it considered the standard...  The simplest way to shorten vowels is to rush to say the following consonant. Try saying "W-LL", "ST", "WTH" without prolonging the "LL", "T" or "TH" (no sound after them at all).

Comment: That's all we can do here. This isn't really a forum where one can practice one's pronunciation.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Just 'cuz *you* can't help the OP doesn't mean that none of us can!

Comment: I meant that's all we should do. I voted to close.

Comment: @Brian not sure, but I think getting help on how to pronounce stuff is on-topic, since we have some questions about that.

Comment: Well, yes, pronunciation is in scope, but without audio it's very difficult to convey. Some questioners have actually sent audio of themselves, so we could comment.  Of course, IPA advocates say it's all one needs, but if OP hasn't learned IPA, that doesn't help.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, inazemaR.A.M OK, I've done my best below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/i:/ is the vowel that we find in the word *FLEECE*. I put that word in capitals because that is how that vowel is often referred to by linguists: the *fleece vowel* - or *FLEECE* for short. (This is not random, the word was specifically chosen for a number of specific reasons.) It is the vowel sound at the end of the word *guarantee*. In transcriptions of British English it has a colon [ : ] in the symbol to describe the length.

/ɪ/ is the vowel in the word *KIT*. It is known as the *kit vowel* - or *KIT* for short. It is the vowel we find in prefixes and suffixes, the bits we stick onto the beginnings and ends of words. So, for example it is the vowel we hear in *--ing* verb endings. We can also hear it in the words *will*, *sit* and *with*.

If you say the < y > sound that we find in the word *yes*, and then say the < e>  we find in the word *end*, the kit vowel is somewhere between the two sounds. This is the first vowel in the word *infinitely*. This word would sound very odd to a native speaker if it was said with a fleece vowel, /i:/! It would sound like a made-up word:  *eenfinitely*.

One way to try and make a good KIT vowel is to try to make a sound that's half way between the /i:/ in *seat* and the /e/ in *set*. If you aren't used to making the KIT vowel, it should be difficult to tell whether the word you're making sounds like /i/ or /e/. If it sounds a bit like both, but not very like either one then you're on the right track.

Another trick is to say the sound /i:/ for a very long time, maybe for five seconds or so. Now do the same with the vowel /e/. Now do the same thing again but change the vowel very slowly so that it starts on /i/ and ends on /e/. You need to do this very, very slowly so that you can only just hear the vowel changing. After you've done this a couple of times, stop half way through and listen to that sound. Try and hold that sound for a few seconds. Next, listen to [this video from BBC learning English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNFKG0yvDx4). Does the speaker's KIT vowel sound sound more like an /e/ than yours? If so, you need to make it more /e/-like. If it sounds more /i/-like, then you need to make ours more /i/-like too.

One last tip: very often, but not always, learners find it difficult to say the KIT vowel when it's the main vowel in the word, but they say it very well in prefixes and suffixes in English. So if your KIT vowel in **in**teresting is different from your kit vowel in **sit**, the vowel you are making in **in**teresting is the one you want to use in the word **sit**. If these vowels are the same for you, then try the vowel at the *end* of interest**ing**. If that vowel is different from the vowel you use in **sit**, try using that vowel in the word **sit** instead. Try using this vowel when repeating the words on the linked-to video.

Remember, there's nothing like frequent practise for improving your ear. Keep listening to videos like the one I linked to. Record yourself and listen back. Do this frequently, but not for long periods of time (otherwise you'll get very bored!).

Good luck!

Comment: Is that answer suitable for American English as well?

Comment: Well, I would not agree that -ing suffixes sound like the  "kit" I. Not even close.  the -ing is a special case; you really can't separate out the I sound in it.

Comment: But Araucaria is right on about beginning I  as in infinite:  >This is the first vowel in the word infinitely. This word would sound very odd to a native speaker if it was said with a fleece vowel, /i:/! It would sound like a made-up word: eenfinitely  <>  I have heard a New Zealander do exactly that, and it sure sounded strange to my AmE ears!

Comment: @brian is right about "ing" in Gen Am. There's a neutralisation between KIT and SCHWA in weak vowels in Gen Am, which we don't have in SSBE, so best to use the first syllable there.

Comment: @Araucaria: I don't actually know if that neutralization is relevant here. But not a lot of vowel phonemes are possible before /ŋ/, and possibly as a consequence, there's a lot of variation in the phonetic realization of vowels in this position. Depending on the person, dialect, or even level of formality, the vowel in the "-ing" ending may be identified with KIT, FLEECE, or perhaps as you said "schwa."